# Regex look-ahead with non-capturing group not working as intended

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Below I have text from which I want to extract the month (July in this case).
The `word_pattern` makes sure that the text contains those words,
while the `month_pattern` will extract the month. So first I verify text passage
contains certain words, and if it does, then I attempt to extract the `month`

When the patterns are used separately, they get a match, but if I try to combine them
I end up with no matches.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import re

text = ''' The number of shares of the
registrant’s common stock outstanding as
of July 31, 2017 was 52,833,429.'''

# patterns
word_pattern = r'(?=.*outstanding[.,]?)(?=.*common)(?=.*shares)'

month_pattern = r'(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)'


pattern = word_pattern + month_pattern

print(re.search(pattern, text, flags = re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL))
```

Expected result:

<re.Match object; span=(73, 77), match='July'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex cannot be easily concatenated like that. The issue is your word pattern only uses lookaheads and therefore does not move the position ahead which becomes a problem when the month only shows up mid-string. So, you need to allow the cursor to advance to the month position using a quantifier that bridges the gap, e.g. `.*` Try

```
(?=.*outstanding[.,]?)(?=.*common)(?=.*shares).*(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EXr9Se/1/)

Or `pattern = word_pattern +'.*'+ month_pattern` should do the trick.

The result can be found in capture group 1: `re.search(...).group(1)`